# Selenium WebDriver без добавления файла в path

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

В документации к **Selenium** описана первичная настройка окружения, что нужно импортировать/подключить селениум и скачать файл драйвера необходимого браузера, затем сделать так, чтобы этот файл был доступен в **Path**. С таким подходом не возникает проблем.

В моей задаче нужно сконфигурировать **Builder** таким образом, чтобы не было необходимости скачивать драйвер, а это делалось автоматически.

Меня направили в сторону **Selenium Webdriver Manager**, но его реализация на **Javascript** иная, а внятной документации мне найти не удалось.

Вот пример что видел на просторах интернета применимое к **Python**:

```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
   driver.get(url)
```

Помимо этого возникает вопрос и по установке локализации экземпляра браузера при его создании, те варианты, которые мне попадались - не работают.

Вот ситуация пока такая. Заранее спасибо за советы.

Comment: Если более кратко Вам нужен пример использования WebdriverManager для node.js?

Comment: Если более кратко Вам нужен пример использования WebdriverManager для node.js? - думаю да